# How to remove Shopify Logo icon from my web store?

Tags: shopify

There's a floating Shopify logo icon displayed at the bottom of my all pages in my store.

I wish to remove that from my store, I don't know how to remove that icon.

Can anyone help me to fix that issue.?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are logged into Shopify admin while you are viewing your store. The icon is basically a short cut to access Shopify admin console. Log out from your Shopify admin or view your store in private browsing mode.